# Reverse the blade tool (merge clips together)

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro-x

I'm trying to make a transition to Final Cut Pro X from iMovie. Although I'm finding it quite simple and I'm in love with the more advanced features such as how easy keying is, I seem to have a problem I'm not sure how to get around.

I want to be able to "undo" the blade tool, in effect merging clips together. How can I do this?

I'm aware of the compound clip feature, but that lacks the "I'm done here, move on" feeling I get from a clip that doesn't have a bunch of visible edits to it.

Comment: ah completely didn't notice the X part - i'll delete my answer :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If that's a cut within the same clip, you can move the right edge of the first clip to the end of the second clip, to restore the formerly length.
- If you want to combine different clips to make some pivotal changes or append centrical effects. You have to create a compound clip.
- If it was a cut within one clip, you can simply undo it. But i hope you know that.

I dont' know what you mean with "I'm-done-here-move-on-feeling", but a typical project has hundreds and thousands cuts. That's absolutely normal.